# Classify data and design mysql

Tags: mysql

My website has 100.000 views per day. And table album contains all album user upload to website. There are some popular users who are usually visited by many people and some normal people. I want to design my database how to seperate 2 kinds of users.
What should I do ?

Comment: to increase performance and reduce load you might be better of with a caching system, otherwise I don't really see why you would do that.

Answer (score 0):

The usual design standards for databases (which are, arguably, not always right) would state that if the users have the same properties, you should store them in the same data abstraction (table, in this case). This reduces the loading times in cases where someone does not want to see one of the top 10 people. It's preferrable to adjust loading times for all people, not only for the top 10. If you still need to increase performance for certain records, you could either look into indexes (and post some queries so we can take a look) and/or take a look at [load balancing systems for MySQL](http://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian).